# How to make custom Op in TensorFlow importable in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, bazel

I have implemented a kernel for my custom Op, and put it into `/tensorflow/core/user_ops` as `custom_op.cc`. Inside the Op I do all the registering stuff, like `REGISTER_OP` and `REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER`.

Then I implemented gradient for this Op in Python, and I put it in the same folder as `custom_op_grad.py`. I did all the registering here as well (`@ops.RegisterGradient`).

I have created the BUILD file, with the following content:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")
tf_custom_op_library(
        name = "custom_op.so",
        srcs = ["custom_op.cc"],
)

py_library(
        name = "custom_op_grad",
        srcs = ["custom_op_grad.py"],
        srcs_version = "PY2",
        deps = [
        ":custom_op_grad",
        "//tensorflow:tensorflow_py",
        ],
)
```

After that, I rebuild Tensorflow:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
bazel clean
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
cp -r bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles/__main__/* bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles/
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

When I try to use my Op after all this, by calling `tf.user_ops.custom_op` it tells me that module doesn't have it.

Maybe there are some additional steps I have to do? Or I am doing something wrong with the `BUILD` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I just removed the `BUILD` file, and my custom Op was successfully built and was importable in Python using `tensorflow.user_ops.custom_op()`.

To use the gradient I had to put it's code directly inside the `tensorflow/python/user_ops/user_ops.py`. Not the most elegant solution, but working for now.